# adding parts to a list that haven't already been added

Tags: python, list

```
f = ''
da = ['A', 'T', 'G', 'C', ' ']
fnn = []
print(fnn)

con = 0

x = input('Corrupted: ')
nx = list(x)

for nx in nx:
    if nx[con] in da:
        f = f + str(nx[con])
    else:
        pass

fn = f.split()

print(fn)
print(fn[0])

for i in fn:
    if fn[i] not in fnn:
        fnn = fnn.extend(fn[i])
    else:
        pass

print(fnn)
```

This script is meant to read the input then remove all letters except from `A C G T` and remove any repeating sequences that point at it, I am really struggling to get it to remove the repeating sequences, what do i need to do? what am i doing wrong? and are there any quicker ways to do this?

Comment: It is very unclear what your question is.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does several odd things:

- `nx = list(x)` - why turn x into a list? You can iterate through a string just as easily
- `for nx in nx` (as already mentioned)
- `if nx[con] in da` - what is this trying to achieve? What is con?
- `str(nx[con])` - nx[0] is already a string
- `else: pass` - no need to include the else condition if you're just going to pass
- `extend` extends a list in place, so no need to write `my_list = my_list.extend...` (and in fact you will lose the list this way)
- `fnn.extend(fn[i])` - if the previous part of the code worked correctly then `fn[i]` would probably be a string; and you probably don't want to extend a list by a string.

Try experimenting to see what this does:

```
x = ['cat', 'dog']
x.extend('mouse')
print x
```

I think what you want is something like this. Note the use of descriptive variable names to help the reader understand what the code does.

```
permitted_characters = 'ATGC '
corrupted = input('Corrupted: ')

# Remove characters that are not permitted and split string into sequences
sequences = ''.join(c for c in corrupted if c in permitted_characters).split()

# Remove repeated sequences
unique_sequences = []
for sequence in sequences:
    if not sequence in unique_sequences:
        unique_sequences.append(sequence)
```

Answer (score 0):

`for nx in nx:`

Well firstly, you're overriding the list, so `nx[con]` won't work.